# Lambda expression error

Tags: c#, winforms, lambda

I have an issue that's eating my head for the past couple of days. I am unable to find a solution.

I am trying to find the occurrence of '\' in a string using lambda expressions. Here's the code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range labelSupportTopic = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[resultRange.Row, 29];
int count = labelSupportTopic.Text.ToString().Count(c => c == '\\');
```

I am getting the date from an Excel sheet, therefore the Interop reference.

What's bothering me is that this code is **copied and pasted** from an exact same VS project whose most of the code I lost somehow. I was lucky to have some part and this was one of it. Regardless, on my other VS project (the one whose code I lost), I am able to Build and it looks fine. But my current project, the one I built from scratch, it throws an error on Build. This entire section, the one that contains this logic is lifted off from my old project (which Builds fine). The error reads "*Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type*" I searched the internet but I was unable to find a solution.

Can you help, please?!

Comment: If you run your code in debug mode, can you see if `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range` is `dynamic`? If it is, that's your problem. You can't use lambdas or extension methods with dynamic.

Comment: `...ToString().Count((Predicate<char>)(c => c == '\\'));`

Comment: @Connor Thanks for the reply. The marked answer fixed it!

Comment: @JakubDąbek Your response seemed to have fixed the issue with Build (it Build without errors) but it still wouldn't count the number of \ in the string. Thanks for looking in though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count = (labelSupportTopic.Text as string).Count('\\'.Equals);
```

Because the type of `.Text` is [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic), the type of `.ToString()` is also `dynamic`, and the type of `c` in the lambda expression can't be inferred.

In earlier versions of C# that don't have the `dynamic` keyword (before VS 2010), the type of `.Text` is `object` and your original version should compile without issues.

Comment: I wouldn't use `as` since it implies that you expect it might not be a string, and it would just result in a null reference exception if the text property happens not to be a string. Either use a regular cast if you expect it always to be a string and it would be an error not to be a string, or else use the null coalescing operator to default it to `""` in cases where it's not a string. Otherwise I think this answer is correct.

Comment: @Sahuagin you are right, but I find this form a bit more readable than `((string)(labelSupportTopic.Text))`. `.Text` can return null for a `Range` with different text values, but for a single cell it results in at least `""`, so I removed the `?? ""` from my initial sample.

Comment: That seemed to have fixed the issue. What I don't understand it, despite having the exact code copied and pasted from another project, it wouldn't work. Any idea what it'd do that? Honestly, I didn't change a thing.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson as I mentioned, your original version would work in older versions where `.Text` returns `object` instead of `dynamic`. There must be some small difference between the two projects settings.

Comment: @Slai There was hardly a gap of an hour, so I don't suppose version is the reason. Besides, I did not update VS at all. But regardless, thanks for helping. The product is fully functional now.